# Algorithm in the tag clouds (Calculating)

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, grouping

I have a tag list which contains a list of duplicated tags, such as "tag1", "tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag3" and "tag2".

I want to calculate and how many tag1, tag2 and tag3 are in the list, and then add them into a new tag list such as `var tagList = new List<Tag>()`, it will have thousands of the tags in the list. Can anyone one help me to achieve this in an effective way? The list should have the tag name and the number of tags (count).

Here is the my `Tag` class properties:

```
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public int TagCount { get; set; }
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell from your description if you have an `IEnumerable<string>` representing the tags or an `IEnumerable<Tag>` representing the tags so here is an approach for both:

For the `Tag` case:

```
List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>() {
    new Tag() { TagName = "tag1" },
    new Tag() { TagName = "tag1" },
    new Tag() { TagName = "tag2" },
    new Tag() { TagName = "tag3" },
    new Tag() { TagName = "tag3" },
    new Tag() { TagName = "tag2" }
};
var tagList = tags.GroupBy(t => t.TagName)
                  .Select(g => new Tag() {
                      TagName = g.Key,
                      TagCount = g.Count()
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

For the `string` case:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() {
    "tag1",
    "tag1",
    "tag2",
    "tag3",
    "tag3",
    "tag2"
};
var tagList = list.GroupBy(s => s)
                  .Select(g => new Tag() {
                      TagName = g.Key,
                      TagCount = g.Count() 
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

In both cases I used the definition

```
class Tag {
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public int TagCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you! But tag list is the List<Tag> not the List<string>. :)

Comment: Thank you very much Jason. I understand this now. Is there any thing I could to ignore case during the group by?

Comment: Sure, you could replace `t => t.TagName` in the above by `t => t.TagName.ToLower()`.

Comment: Thank you Jason. It works great for me. I was wandering how this can be done in the old days without Linq.

Comment: You're dropping the TagID.  I hope it's not important.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, I think this will work.  You want to group by the tag id and name, then sum the count for each of the tags in the existing list.

```
var tagList = existingList.GroupBy( t => new { t.TagID, t.TagName } )
                          .Select( g => new Tag {
                                         TagID = g.Key.TagID,
                                         TagName = g.Key.TagName,
                                         TagCount = g.Sum( t => t.TagCount )
                          })
                          .ToList();
```